# Can you determine a set of values from a set of distinct sums

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, information-theory

Consider an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) of positive integers $A$ of length $n$. Now consider the set of sums of all the contiguously indexed subarrays of $A$. For example if $A = (1,3,5,6)$ then the set would be $S_A = \{1,3,5,6,4,8,11,9,14,15\}$.

> If the sums of all contiguously indexed subarrays are distinct (as they are in the example above), does
>   the set of these sums uniquely specify the set of integers in the array the sums were
>   calculated from?

We can certainly compute the smallest element in the original array as it is the smallest element in $S_A$.  Similarly there must be a value in the original array which is the largest value in $S_A$ minus the second largest.

To show one of the subtleties of this problem, consider $A = (1, 6, 2, 3)$ and $S_A = \{1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 11, 12\}$.  We can immediately tell from $S_A$ that $1$ occurs somewhere in $A$. Similarly we can tell that $2$ occurs somewhere in $A$.  But what can we tell about $3$?  If $1$ and $2$ were next to each then as $1+2=3$ we would know that $3$ can't be in $A$. But if $1$ and $2$ are not next to each in $A$ then we know $3$ must be in $A$.  How do we tell which case we are in?

---

The answer turns out to be **NO**. Take $A = (4, 6, 5, 2, 1)$ and $B = (3, 8, 2, 4, 1)$. We have that $S_A = S_B$ but the set of elements in $A$ and $B$ are distinct.

Comment: interesting problem...  seems it must be true :) but i am only about halfway to proving it.  may i ask: where did this problem come from?

Comment: @antkam Thanks. I am afraid I just became interested in a class of similar problems out of personal interest. I agree it feels like it must be true!

Comment: yeah, there have been a few questions recently (in the last few months) dealing with subsequence sums of an array.  so i was just wondering where all the common interest comes from.  :)  OK, lets clarify a few things: (1) $S_A$ is a SET, so you should use curly braces like $S_A = \{1,3,5,...\}$.  (2) your highlighted question asks does $S_A$ uniquely specify the SET of integers, e.g. $\{1, 3, 5, 6\}$, but is that what you mean?  Or do you mean to ask if $S_A$ uniquely specify the SEQUENCE (ARRAY) of integers e.g. $(1,3,5,6)$ -- which may still be true, modulo sequence reversal $(6,5,3,1)$?

Comment: @antkam I asked about the set only because it’s a weaker claim. That is it is more likely to be true. Of course if it’s also true for the array, modulo reversal, that’s even better. (Fixed bracket error now)

Comment: If $S_A$ is a set, shouldn't it be $\{1,3,4,\cdots\}$, i.e. an ordered list without repetitions ?

Comment: @GCab It doesn't have to be ordered but it is without repetitions, as you say.  I wrote it in the order you see in the question to make it easier to see where the individual integers came from.

Comment: This is a version of the “turnpike” problem, or equivalently the “partial digest” problem.  It is known that there can be very many distinct arrays with the same set of substring sums for large $n$, however I am not aware of any results with the restriction that all the sums are distinct.  Nice question.

Comment: Is the original set ordered and the resulting set not ordered?

Comment: For your specific example you may find that the only values possible in the original set are - 1, 2, 3, 6.

Comment: @Moti Yes arrays are ordered so $A$ is ordered but $S_A$ is not.  For your second comment, my question is can we always uniquely identify the set of elements in the original array from the set of sums?

Comment: So, you mean that an array $(1,2)$ is different from an array $(2,1)$. But then both give the same set $\{1,2,3\}$. So, the answer is no?

Comment: @mathlove No sorry that isn't right. The question is if for all arrays A (which are ordered) does $S_A$ (unordered) uniquely determine the set (unordered) of integers in A under the constraint that the subarray sums of A are all distinct. In your example the set $\{1,2,3\}$ does indeed tell us that A contains exactly the integers 1 and 2 (but not their order).

Comment: I think you should add your counterexample as an answer and accept it.

Comment: what a surprise ending!  (surprising to me anyway)  how did you find the counterexample?  search by a program?  hand-crafted?  BTW i agree w/ @leonbloy that you should post it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The question is if we have a solution at all for A order given S - if we limit the maximum to the sum of A.

Comment: @Moti I don’t see how that is the question.  Isn’t that just a finite problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer turns out to be **NO**. Take $A = (4, 6, 5, 2, 1)$ and $B = (3, 8, 2, 4, 1)$. We have that $S_A = S_B$ but the set of elements in $A$ and $B$ are distinct.

Comment: how did you find the counterexample? search by a program? hand-crafted?

Comment: @antkam I wrote some code. There are no counter examples with arrays of length shorter than 5.

Comment: To clarify, there are no counter examples at all for length < 5 since it is known that every array of length $\le 4$ is uniquely determined (up to reversal) by its multi set of substring sums.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes. I still have no good feeling at all about this problem  area.  Which arrays of length > 4 are uniquely determined  (up to reversal) by the set of substring sums?   Are any necessary conditions  known?

Comment: There is a decent amount known about this actually.  I recommend reading “Reconstructing Sets from Interpoint Distances” by Skiena, Smith, Lemke, which you should be able to find a PDF for.  They give a nice argument that the set of solutions for a given set of sums has a hypercube structure, in particular it is always a power of $2$ (if non-zero).

Comment: @ErickWong Am I right that doesn't cover the set case, just the multi set case?

Comment: @Anush The multiset case is more general as the distinctness is a restriction on the *sums*, not on the inputs.  So it easily covers both cases.